# Did Allah sent a prophet to every ethnicity?

Tags: prophets

Salam alaikoum,

I am wondering if Allah ta'ala sent to each ethnicity a prophet, for example countries like Russia, Japan, South america..

Thank you.

Comment: At the time the quran was revealed some languages and cultures we now know didn't even exist.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Medi1Saif , yes I agree with you but many other civilisations (not civilisations, but more "contries") were already existing at revelation time

Comment: *...no nation but that there had passed within it a warner...* ([Qur'an 35:24](https://quran.com/35/24)) implies they had a "warner", or a "messenger", but not necessarily a prophet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did God send a prophet for every ethnic group?
In the Holy Qur'an, God Almighty has stated a general law about all the prophets, including the Prophet of Islam (PBUH) and all the nations, including the nation that lived in the time of the Prophet (PBUH): [1] " And every nation has a messenger, so when their messenger comes, it will be judged between them with justice, and they will not be wronged.” [2] For every nation, there is a messenger, so when their messenger comes to them, justice will be judged among them and they will not be wronged.
In other words, after the arrival of the Prophet and the propagation of the mission and the completion of the argument, there will be a fair treatment of the people. The believers will prosper and the disbelievers will be punished and no one will be oppressed.

A prophet can be for one village only, and a prophet for all the worlds. Of course, it is God who determines the scope of the mission of each of them. [4] Of course, every prophet is naturally aroused among a group and in certain areas, and his guidance must begin from there, and it is natural that he must be their language in order to be able to communicate well with them, but his circle of prophethood can be wider than time and Place to be evaluated. Many prophets, after warning and inviting the people who were sent among them, if possible for them, invited people from other regions and in other languages as well. (5)

[1]. Makarim Shirazi, Nasir, Tafsir Namouna, Part 8, p. 305, Tehran, Dar al-Islamiyyah al-Kutub, First Chap., 1374 Sh.
[2]. Yunus, 47.
[4]. Inaam, 124.

Ref: http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa76488